# python Tkinter adjust label font but not label size

Tags: python, tkinter

please teach me how to adjust the label font size to fit the label width&height. right now, whenever i adjust my label font size, the label size gets bigger as well. below is my code :

```
self.the_font = tkFont.Font(family="helvetica", size=18)

self.table_num = Tkinter.StringVar()
self.tbl_num = Tkinter.Label(self, anchor="c",fg="black", bg = "orange", width = 15, height = 7, font = self.the_font, relief="sunken", textvariable = self.table_num)
self.tbl_num.place(relx = .75, rely = .5, anchor = "c")
```

then later, my another function will update the label as below :

```
def GetINFO(self) :
    ID_input = self.user_text.get()
    ID_input = ID_input.strip("\n")
    ID_input = ID_input.strip(" ")

    ID_input = int(ID_input)

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
    A = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Full List')

    for index, row in enumerate(A.iter_rows()):

        row_details = [cell.value for cell in row]

        for data in row_details :
            #data = data.strip()
            #data  = int(data)
            if data == ID_input :
                HID_num = row_details[0]
                emp_num = row_details[1]
                emp_name = row_details[2]
                tbl_num = row_details[3]

    self.employee_name.set(emp_name)
    self.employee_id.set(emp_num)
    self.reg_status.set("Registered")

    size = self.the_font.cget("size")
    size += 7
    self.the_font.configure(size=size)
    self.table_num.set(tbl_num)
```

it is the table_num that i want adjust the size

Answer (score 0):

If the label displays text, the size is given in text units. If the label displays an image, the size is given in pixels.
If the size is set to 0, or omitted, it is calculated based on the label contents.

> > height depends on the font.

You can get `width` and `height` of the text using `font.mesure()` method:

```
import Tkinter
import tkFont

root = Tkinter.Tk()

the_font = tkFont.Font(family="helvetica", size=36)

w, h = (the_font.measure('test size'), the_font.metrics("linespace"))
```